# postfix relay access denied with SSL on 465

Tags: postfix

I set Postfix and Dovecot up for my server, am using self signed certificates and all is well. I can send email, but what i can't do is send email from my server on say, my iPhone. I'm getting relay access denied.

This is one of the reasons I setup SSL, as I understood this will not be an issue with that. I'm now wondering if the anonymous TLS connection is because I'm using self signed certificates, or because i am not logging in properly as i should. My mail client (mac) is setup to use port 465 and SSL is checked.

My `submission` parameters from `master.conf`:

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

The logs:

```
Jul 12 22:07:24 www postfix/smtpd[29973]: 0020 7a 1a 73 15 eb dc ce 99|                             z.s..... 
Jul 12 22:07:24 www postfix/smtpd[29973]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 read finished A
Jul 12 22:07:24 www postfix/smtpd[29973]: cpc98338-croy25-2-0-cust350.19-2.cable.virginm.net[x.x.x.x]: Reusing old session
Jul 12 22:07:24 www postfix/smtpd[29973]: Anonymous TLS connection established  from cpc98338-croy25-2-0-cust350.19-2.cable.virginm.net[x.x.x.x]: TLSv1.2 with   cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Jul 12 22:07:24 www postfix/smtpd[29973]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from cpc98338-croy25-2-0-cust350.19-2.cable.virginm.net[x.x.x.x]: 554 5.7.1     <info@outlook.com>: Relay access denied; from=<sales@fubar.com> to=    <info@outlook.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.0.14]>
Jul 12 22:07:24 www postfix/smtpd[29973]: disconnect from cpc98338-croy25-2-0-cust350.19-2.cable.virginm.net[x.x.x.x]
```

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Please share the `submission` configuration from `master.conf` with all its parameters.

Comment: Hi Esa, here you go:https://pastebin.com/kvLapTfc

Comment: Submission is related to `587`, smtps is `465`. Edit to fit uncommented line `smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd` and watch for options regarding this line

Comment: Hi Miloshio, can you elaborate, i'm not sure what you mean (i know submission is 587 and smtp is 465) but not sure what else you are referring to. Thanks!

Comment: The similar section for `smtps` than you have for `submission`.

Comment: Here you go Esa: https://pastebin.com/XMczaWn0

Comment: Bump. Anyone? I suspect i get this problem because my client is not really authenticating for some reason, as evidenced by the "setting up anonymous TLS connection" in the maillog, and that's why it is not allowing relay. The mail clients are definitely set to authenticating and use SSL, so it must be some config i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

- something else is wrong, you **can** send email from iPhone (presumably also from iMac email clients) even when only option is plaintext (no ssl/tls) both on port **25** (*this port may be blocked by your ISP though*) and port **587**. Sure it is not adviced to go without SSL/TLS but it is possible and compliant to defined standards. Check `/var/log/mail.log` (on Debian family) or other Postfix/system mail log file to see what happens when you cannot submit mail to 25 or 587. Of course confirm everything is basically correct before that, by **talking SMTP** with your server via telnet: `telnet yourserver.tld 25` and `telnet yourserver.tld 587` . [Here](http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html) and [here](https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/mail/test-smtp-auth-telnet) is a guide.
- Submission is enabled with accomodation of directives in `master.cf` :

  ```
  submission inet n      -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,check_relay_domains,reject
  ```

  note that this `-o`'s are fully dependant to what you have on server, but presented are some common defaults.
- SMTPS (465) is enabled with uncommenting this line:

  ```
  smtps     inet  n       –       –       –       –       smtpd
  ```

  and following `-o`'s. Again, you have to adjust this to your needs, but sane defaults are usually present in `master.cf`
- Of course after any change restart Postfix (no need to say this but can't hurt)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone isn't authenticating for outgoing mail. Probably because you forgot to tell it that it needed to.

Change that and it should work. Or you'll at least have a different problem.

Comment: Hmm i'll check but pretty sure that i am.

Comment: Do i need to authenticate on 465 for SSL or use 587 ?

Comment: Either could work, but the partial config you've posted only shows 587.

Comment: I pasted both, see pastebin.com/XMczaWn0 . I checked and i am also authenticating on either iPhone or mac (tls/ssl is checked and username and password is filled in, so now i'm at a loss. When using 465 ssl i get relay access not allowed, when using 578 i get this account is not owned by sales. Any other config i can post for anyone to have a look? I really appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth to others, the below fixed my relay problem. Hope it helps you.

I fixed the problem by:

-Changing to port 587

-Changing in both smtp and submission in master.cf:

```
-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
```

to :

```
 -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_sender_login_mismatch
```

This now allows me to send mail from user sales to anyone once logged into the server.

The anonymous connection established message:

```
Jul 30 10:36:47 www postfix/smtpd[9618]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
Jul 30 10:36:47 www postfix/smtpd[9618]: Anonymous TLS connection established from cpc98338-croy25-2-0-cust350.19-2.cable.virginm.net[82.45.65.95]: TLSv1.2 with   cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
```

i think is a result of using self signed certificates.

I am still interested to find out why i login with my client as such:

```
Jul 30 10:35:59 www dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<sales>, method=PLAIN, rip=82.45.65.95, lip=172.31.8.87, mpid=9585, TLS, session=<6+DgeoZV4ABSLUFf>
Jul 30 10:35:59 www dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<sales>, method=PLAIN, rip=82.45.65.95, lip=172.31.8.87, mpid=9608, TLS, session=<Ze/neoZV4gBSLUFf>
Jul 30 10:36:46 www postfix/smtpd[9618]: initializing the server-side TLS engine
Jul 30 10:36:46 www postfix/smtpd[9618]: connect from cpc98338-blu-25-2-0-cust350.19-2.cable.virginm.net[82.x.x.x]
Jul 30 10:36:46 www postfix/smtpd[9618]: setting up TLS connection from cpc98338-blu-25-2-0-cust350.19-2.cable.virginm.net[82.x.x.x]
Jul 30 10:36:46 www postfix/smtpd[9618]: cpc98338-blu-25-2-0-cust350.19-2.cable.virginm.net[82.x.x.x]: TLS cipher list "ALL:!EXPORT:!LOW:+RC4:@STRENGTH"
Jul 30 10:36:46 www postfix/smtpd[9618]: SSL_accept:before/accept initializati
```

And others (spammers presumably) i see a message like this:

```
    Jul 30 10:54:09 www postfix/smtpd[9686]: warning: unknown[80.82.78.85]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
    Jul 30 10:54:09 www postfix/smtpd[9686]: disconnect from unknown[80.82.78.85]
```

Hmm probably because they login on port 25 (smtpd).